# Number of solutions to $z=4e^z$ inside the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I might have solved it but I don't know if the methods I used are valid. Please check my work.

$$z=4e^z$$
I apply $z^{-1}$ to both sides to get
$$\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{4}e^{-z}$$

now that's the step I'm worried about. $z$ can't be $0$ for me to do that, and it's easy enough to check that $z$ indeed isn't one of the solutions, but is that enough justification?

In any case, I continue with multiplying both sides with $z$ to get

$$1=\frac{1}{4}ze^{-z}$$

Now applying Rouche's theorem for $f(z)=1$ and $g(z)=-\frac 1 4 ze^{-z}$ I find that there are no solutions inside the unit circle.

Am I allowed to take those two steps? If yes, how can I be confident that I didn't perhaps introduce new solutions, or wipe out existing ones? If not, why not?

Comment: You can avoid the problem by multiplying with $\frac{1}{4}e^{-z}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmmmm... It really does avoid it. Can you comment on doing what I did on problems where this kind of a shortcut isn't applicable?

Comment: What you do is, if I understand your ideas correctly, to find solutions of $f(z)=g(z)$, you take the reciprocals, so you get the equation $\frac{1}{f(z)}=\frac{1}{g(z)}$, which has the same solutions except for the $z$ with $f(z)=0=g(z)$, and then multiply with $f(z)$, so you get $1=\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$. You can always short-cut that by directly dividing by $g(z)$, provided that $g(z)\neq 0$ [at least for the $z$ solving the original equation]. And that short-cut always avoids the problems your way has for $z$ with $f(z)=0\neq g(z)$. Both ways have problems if there are $z$ with $f(z)=0= g(z)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Fantastic! Great explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|z|=1$, then:
$$\left|4 e^{z}\right| = 4 e^{\text{Re}(z)} \geq 4 e^{-1} > 1=\left|-z\right| $$
so by [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) the two functions $4e^z-z$ and $4e^z$ have the same number of zeroes inside the unit disk, i.e. zero. The same works if we replace the unit disk with any disk with radius $<\frac{6}{5}$.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I missed that. $e^0$ is actually $1$, not $0$...

Answer (score 2):

Since $|LHS| \leq 1$, we must have $|RHS| \leq 1$. So $$4|e^{z}| \leq 1 \\ |e ^ {z}| \leq \frac 1 4 $$ So now split $z$ into $x + iy$. We have $$|\exp(x + iy)| \leq \frac 1 4  \\ |\exp(x)\exp(iy)| \leq \frac 1 4  \\ |\exp(x)| \cdot |\exp(iy)| \leq \frac 1 4  \\|\exp(x)| \leq \frac 1 4  \\ \exp(x) \leq \frac 1 4  \\ x \leq -\log 4$$ But then the LHS is not on the unit circle, because no element on the unit circle has real part less than or equal to $-\log 4 < -1$. Contradiction.

There is no solution in the unit circle.

Comment: It's a good argument, but the question was about solutions inside of the circle, not on it. Also, I'm not convinced that the step I took to GET to the equation you started with is valid.

Comment: @LukaHorvat I modified the argument because I misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$
|z|=|x+iy|\le 1 \Rightarrow |4e^z|=4e^x \le1 \Rightarrow x\le - \log (4)
$$